# alguien sabe como puedo esperar que termine la llamada a un API y después seguir con mi código

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic, async-await

Estoy trabajando con ionic y hago una llamada a un API el cual me devuelve un valor para hacer una validación, el problema es que hace la validación sin esperar que termina la llamada del API

Este es el metodo de validacion

```
validar() {
    if (this.validacion == "1") {

      this.usuariosServicio.intentosUsu(this.user).subscribe((Usuarios) => {
        this.listaUsuarios = Usuarios;
        if (this.listaUsuarios[0] != null) {
          this.valorbloqueos = this.listaUsuarios[0].intentos;
        }
      });

      if (this.valorbloqueos >= 0 && this.valorbloqueos < 3) {
        if (this.user == this.usuBD && this.pass == this.claveEnc) {
          this.intentos = 0;

          this.usuariosServicio
            .cambiarestado(this.user, this.intentos)
            .subscribe((Usuarios) => {
              this.listaUsuarios = Usuarios;
            });

          this.usuariosServicio
            .llenarBitacoraAcceso(this.user, this.intentos)
            .subscribe((Usuarios) => {
              this.listaUsuarios = Usuarios;
            });

          this.presentAlert("Informacion", "", "Logueo Exitoso.");
        } else {
          this.presentAlert("Informacion", "", "La contraseña es incorrecta.");
          //obtener intentos y setearlos en sumaintentos + 1
          //llenar bitacora
          //cambiar estado
          this.usuariosServicio.intentosUsu(this.user).subscribe((Usuarios) => {
            this.listaUsuarios = Usuarios;
            if (this.listaUsuarios[0] != null) {
              this.intentos2 = this.listaUsuarios[0].intentos;
              this.sumaintentos = this.intentos2 + 1;
            }
          });

          this.usuariosServicio
            .llenarBitacoraAcceso(this.user, this.intentos2)
            .subscribe((Usuarios) => {
              this.listaUsuarios = Usuarios;
            });

          this.usuariosServicio
            .cambiarestado(this.user, this.sumaintentos)
            .subscribe((Usuarios) => {
              this.listaUsuarios = Usuarios;
            });
        }
      } else {
        this.presentAlert(
          "Informacion",
          "",
          "El usuario se encuentra Bloqueado."
        );
      }
    } else {
      this.presentAlert(
        "Informacion",
        "",
        "Usuario no registrado en el sistema."
      );
    }
    
  }
```

por ejemplo necesito que el if:

```
if (this.valorbloqueos >= 0 && this.valorbloqueos < 3) {
```

se realice cuando este llamado: haya concluido

```
this.usuariosServicio.intentosUsu(this.user).subscribe((Usuarios) => {
        this.listaUsuarios = Usuarios;
        if (this.listaUsuarios[0] != null) {
          this.valorbloqueos = this.listaUsuarios[0].intentos;
        }
      });
```

Lo mismo lo necesito para los otros llamados a la API pero con solo que me expliquen como hago el primero yo hago el resto

creo que lo que necesito es asyn await pero nose como utilizarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La llamada es asincrona, por lo que las validaciones deben incluirse dentro de la llamada. Cada una de esas llamadas son concluidas cuando se termina de ejecutar el codigo dentro de la funcion definida en `subscribe(func)`:

```
this.usuariosServicio.intentosUsu(this.user).subscribe((Usuarios) => {
    this.listaUsuarios = Usuarios;
    if (this.listaUsuarios[0] != null) {
      this.valorbloqueos = this.listaUsuarios[0].intentos;
    }
    // insertar validaciones Aqui
    if (this.valorbloqueos >= 0 && this.valorbloqueos < 3) {
       
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok entiendo pero agregar todo el código de validar dentro de la función asíncrona va a ser algo complicado pero se puede hacer.

Comment: Lo que quiero es una manera en la cual pueda esperar que termine la función asíncrona para seguir con la validación.

Comment: Gracias si me funciono, creo que no es lo mas optimo pero funciona muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usando [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise). Fetch usa promesas!

```
fetch(URL)
.then(data => ejecutoAlgo())
.then(data=> ejecutoOtraCosa())
.catch(err=> console.log("Algo salio mal");
```

Comment: Pero como lo aplico a mi codigo